# Вывод всех записей из таблицы используя WHERE

Tags: php, sql

Есть код:

```
$id = "1";
$name = "петя"; 
$year = "20";

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '".$id."' AND WHERE name = '".$name."' AND WHERE year = '".$year."'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

}
```

В данном случае выведет строку с id = 1, именем петя и возрастом 20.

Как сделать вывод всех пользователей с именем "петя" не меняя запрос, что то типа:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = * AND WHERE name = 'петя' AND WHERE year = *
```

Сделать при помощи нескольких запросов я могу, но как именно сделать чтобы одним?

Мне нужно именно одним запросом, раньше я делал так:

```
if ($_GET['autor']!="0") $param .= "autor = '".$_GET['autor']."' AND ";
if ($_GET['izdatel']!="0") $param .= "izdatel = '".$_GET['izdatel']."' AND ";
if ($_GET['obrazec']!="0") 
if ($_GET['obrazec']=="Да")
$param .= "obrazec > 0 AND ";
else
$param .= "obrazec = 0 AND ";
if ($_GET['class']!=0) $param .= "class = ".$_GET['class']." AND ";
}
$param = substr($param, 0, -4);
if ($param != "") $param = " WHERE ".$param;
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products".$param);
```

Но данный способ занимает много места. Я хотел бы узнать, можно ли сделать это одним запросом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите уточнения по `id` и `year`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'петя'
```

Если надо, чтобы условия игнорировались, можно так, но это костыль, и не делайте так совсем:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = id AND name = 'петя' AND year = year
```

В вашем случае, с переменными, так (но, умоляю, всё же, не делайте так):

```
$id = "'1'"; // чтобы не учитывать, ставим $id = "id"
$name = "'петя'"; 
$year = "'20'"; // чтобы не учитывать, ставим $year = "year"

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id AND name = $name AND year = $year");
```

Comment: думаю Гена имел другое. Он не хочет использовать динамическое построение запроса(то есть менять сам текст запрос)

Comment: Я надеюсь, что он просто неправильно сформулировал эту элементарную задачу, но по текущей формулировке будет так

Comment: Мой ответ одним запросом вытягивает все записи с именем "петя". Что ещё вы понимаете под "одним запросом"?

Comment: Alexander Grushko прочитайте внимательно вопрос

Comment: Напишите правильно вопрос.

Comment: Тот код, который вы здесь кинули без форматирования - это код формирования запроса со множеством условий. В вопросе вы спросили, как вытащить все записи с именем "петя". Или комментарий и вопрос пишут два разных человека?

Comment: Alexander Grushko я добавил в вопрос способ которым я делал раньше

Comment: Alexander Grushko а почему так не следует делать?

Comment: Потому что, если код хоть сколько-нибудь разрастётся в будущем, будет очень трудно с ним работать, нельзя сходу понять, в чём логика присваивания $id = "id", например

Comment: Для понимания кода я бы рекомендовал оставить, как было раньше. Много кода - не всегда плохо, а чаще, даже, хорошо для понимания и поддержки, если этот код помогает понять логику

Comment: у меня в проекте все распределено по маленьким скриптам так что путаницы не будет